# Define Foreign Key with Fluent API for entity with no navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use Entity Framework Code First.

I have a class **Post** with an association to **User**:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Post 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text{ get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The code above correctly generates primary key (**Id**) for **User** and foreign key (**UserId**) for **Post** due to Code First Conventions.

But what if I don't want to have navigation property (**User**) in **Post** class? Removing that

```
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

results in foreign key **not** auto-generated for **Post**.

Can this be done with Fluent API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can establish the association from the other side:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want a `Posts` property either the answer is: no, you can't. The reason is that EF must be able to track the association *in the object model* in order to insert correct foreign key values when inserting `Post` objects.

Moreover, you wouldn't be able to associate `Post`s and `User`s in your code without at least one navigation property.

**Addition**

And I forgot to mention that, working code-first, EF looks at associations in the class model to create foreign keys in the database.

Comment: Thx. My superaim was exactly having no navigation properties. So now I know - it's impossible :)